# Java naming convention for add only if not existent

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

I have some data structures that stay unchanged if you try to add something that already exists in the data structure. The decision is maybe made through comparing a key or using a equals function. Only if the instance of the object is new to the structure it will be added to the structure.

I was wondering how do you name these kind of methods? `updateX()`, `addX()`, `putX()` are all misleading, but something like `addIfXDoesntExist()` is ugly.

Is there a convention or a quasi standard or anything that just sounds good and is short but at the same time comprehensive?

Comment: If it's of any help, [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) simply calls this "`add`".

Comment: `ConcurrentMap` uses `putIfAbsent()`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth java.util.Collections simply calls this `add` too :)

Comment: @KublaiKhan I would only use `put...` for Collections that actually define `put...` - maps and such. Just using `add(T t): boolean` is probably the more generic solution.

Comment: @owlstead - I was just giving an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For logic like this, you can return a boolean, which returns true if it was a successful add, or false if it already existed. This means you can decide whether or not you care about the result or not and perform other additional logic on if statements etc

```
public boolean add(Object o){}
```

They do this within collection implementations a lot.

Comment: From Collections.add() - which you could actually implement: "Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation). Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)". Says it all really.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be to a good idea to create method `boolean tryAdd()` which returns true if element was added or false if it was already in structure. Also it's possible without return type. You may just create and throw  `ElementAlreadyInStructure` checked exception and handle it as you'd like.

Comment: I would vote for this answer if only because `tryAdd(T t): boolean` it is more descriptive than just `add(T t): boolean`. However, as `Collections.add(T t): boolean` already defines the same functionalty, just using add *should* not confuse Java devs.